# Java - For statement resetting Booleans when running through array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

i've been testing and searching page after page but i cant seem to figure this out.

when i use an "if" statement like the code below and check each individual poly it works but i would like to run just 1 "for" statement and be able to check.

The problem is when i run a "for" statement, only the last index of poly becomes collidable... any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also this is run in a thread at 30 fps.

Working code:

```
        if(poly[0].intersects(gamePanel.player.leftBounds)||
                poly[1].intersects(gamePanel.player.leftBounds)||
                poly[2].intersects(gamePanel.player.leftBounds))
            {gamePanel.player.leftCollide = true;}
        else{gamePanel.player.leftCollide = false;}

        if(poly[0].intersects(gamePanel.player.topBounds)||
                poly[1].intersects(gamePanel.player.topBounds)||
                poly[2].intersects(gamePanel.player.topBounds))
            {gamePanel.player.topCollide = true;}
        else{gamePanel.player.topCollide = false;}

        if(poly[0].intersects(gamePanel.player.rightBounds)||
                poly[1].intersects(gamePanel.player.rightBounds)||
                poly[2].intersects(gamePanel.player.rightBounds))
            {gamePanel.player.rightCollide = true;}
        else{gamePanel.player.rightCollide = false;}

        if(poly[0].intersects(gamePanel.player.bottomBounds)||
                poly[1].intersects(gamePanel.player.bottomBounds)||
                poly[2].intersects(gamePanel.player.bottomBounds))
            {gamePanel.player.bottomCollide = true;}
        else{gamePanel.player.bottomCollide = false;}
```

Not working code:

```
   for(int i = 0;i>poly.length;i++){
        if(poly[i].intersects(gamePanel.player.leftBounds))
            {gamePanel.player.leftCollide = true;}
        else{gamePanel.player.leftCollide = false;}

        if(poly[i].intersects(gamePanel.player.topBounds))
            {gamePanel.player.topCollide = true;}
        else{gamePanel.player.topCollide = false;}

        if(poly[i].intersects(gamePanel.player.rightBounds))
            {gamePanel.player.rightCollide = true;}
        else{gamePanel.player.rightCollide = false;}

        if(poly[i].intersects(gamePanel.player.bottomBounds))
            {gamePanel.player.bottomCollide = true;}
        else{gamePanel.player.bottomCollide = false;}
    }
```

Comment: Very sorry, i forgot this wasn't a strictly java based site.

Comment: Where is your `for` code?

Comment: my for code simply replaces poly[0] through poly[2] with a single poly[i] in each if statement and runs while i is less then the length of poly[]

Comment: i think you should post your for code exactly as you have it

Comment: If you want us to help you with your code, you need to include **all** code you want help with.

Comment: edited. as it runs through the polys it sets things correctly but resets them when the next index arrives to check collision

Comment: Your 2 pieces of code above are not equivalent. Rather replace it with the method I show below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so if poly.length is not just 3 then we can change the previous method like so:

```
private boolean hasCollided( ?[] poly, ? bounds )
{
    for ( ? polyX : poly )
    {
        if( polyX.intersects( bounds )  return true;
    }
    return false;        
}
```

Comment: You will need to replace the question marks with the appropriate types.

Comment: thank you very much, i wasn't aware you could use a for statement in any other way than for(;;){} ... i am going to look into this more because i honestly have no clue how this even works lol ... merry christmas!

Comment: See here [the Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

If this code is running in a different thread to the code that uses the fields, you may have a synchronization issue.

The Java Memory Model is allowed to make copies of fields and changes made in one thread may not be visible to other threads.

Try making the fields `volatile` and synchronize all access to the fields on the saneclick object, the easiest way to do thus is add `synchronized` getters for the fields.

Comment: its a single thread, i know the problem is that its running through and finds that poly[1] has not intersected and sets the Boolean back to false i just cant seem to figure out the right way of making it work

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean with the "for" statement, but for starters your code can be reduced as follows:

```
private boolean hasCollided( ?[] poly, ? bounds )
{
    if( poly[0].intersects( bounds ) ||
        poly[1].intersects( bounds ) ||
        poly[2].intersects( bounds ) )  return true;

    return false;        
}
```

Then you would use it like so:

```
gamePanel.player.leftCollide = hasCollided( poly, gamePanel.player.leftBounds );
gamePanel.player.rightCollide = hasCollided( poly, gamePanel.player.rightBounds );
// etc ...
```

Comment: i love you idea, im still new at this so my code is ugly lol. the problem is i have well over 100 index's i figure instead of having 100 poly[0].intersects( bounds ) || i could have a single for statment that ran through all of them ... the problem i am having with the above code is that it runs through all of them but the last check cancels all the previous checks out

Comment: So is poly.length > 100 ?

Comment: yes, would the only way to be to add each one individually? i just figured i could find a work around to reduce code

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that:
If 1st poly has left collide, but 2nd poly don't have left collide.
Your code will set gamePanel.player.leftCollide = true when first time,
but when run second time, it will reset gamePanel.player.leftCollide to false;

so don't reset value to false in the loop. Just init them before loop

You can change code like this:

```
gamePanel.player.leftCollide = false;
gamePanel.player.topCollide = false;
gamePanel.player.rightCollide = false;
gamePanel.player.bottomCollide = false;

for(int i = 0;i>poly.length;i++){
    if(poly[i].intersects(gamePanel.player.leftBounds))
        {gamePanel.player.leftCollide = true;}

    if(poly[i].intersects(gamePanel.player.topBounds))
        {gamePanel.player.topCollide = true;}

    if(poly[i].intersects(gamePanel.player.rightBounds))
        {gamePanel.player.rightCollide = true;}

    if(poly[i].intersects(gamePanel.player.bottomBounds))
        {gamePanel.player.bottomCollide = true;}
}
```